# Matching short but important strings with PostgreSQL full text search

Tags: postgresql

Using the latest stable PostgreSQL, when I perform a full text search using short strings, like `Up` for example, I get no results, even when `Up` is clearly in one or many of the targeted columns of several rows.  For example:

```
SELECT title FROM things WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('Up');
```

Results in a screenful of this line repeating:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
```

Whereas searching for a longer string returns plenty of results. Is there a way I can avoid this and perform the short search anyway without adversely affecting longer searches?

(I'm executing queries via [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [SQLAlchemy-Searchable](https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which sets up the indexes and a trigger automatically, but the issue is clearly at the database level.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Up` is considered a [stopword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) in the English dictionary of PostgreSQL, and for this reason it is not considered for retrieval in full text search. However, you can define your own dictionary to include the words that you are interested in. See this [manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html).

At this link https://superuser.com/questions/479400/list-of-stopwords-in-postgres-9-1 you can find where the stopwords dictionary is located in PostgreSQL.